# Apache CXF - None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied

Tags: java, cxf

I'm trying to create client of 3rd party WS. My app is running on JBoss AS 6 (with its Apache CXF 2.3.1 stack). I generated client code by wsconsume (wsdl2java). When I tried to connect to WS a got exception:

```
No assertion builder for type http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http}BasicAuthentication registered. 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
```

Auth part of WSDL looks like:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="abc_ssl_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <http:BasicAuthentication
                xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http" />
            <sp:TransportBinding
                xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false" />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256 />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Client code:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "Abc", 
              wsdlLocation = "https://hiddendomain.com/abc/abc.svc?wsdl",
              targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")                  
public class Abc extends Service {

public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "Abc");
public final static QName AbcSsl = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "abc_ssl");
static {

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "pas".toCharArray());
        }

    });

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://hiddendomain.com/abc/abc.svc?wsdl");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DistrInfo.class.getName())
            .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                 "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "...");
    }
    WSDL_LOCATION = url;
}
```

Exception is thrown whe I try get Conduit:

```
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    HTTPConduit con = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit(); <- exception
```

I suspect that is because of non-standard MS policy and I need proper Intercerptor to handle this policy, but can somebody show me a way how to do it?

I dont even no, where I should put my HTTPS credentials to auth (I can't get conduit)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem gone when I used this code:

```
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;

...

JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

//factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
//factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());

factory.setServiceClass(IAbc.class);
factory.setAddress("https://hiddendomain.com/abc/abc.svc/soap"); <- must be /soap there, otherwise 404

IAbc info = (IAbc) factory.create();

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(info);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

http.getAuthorization().setUserName("user");
http.getAuthorization().setPassword("pass");

String abc = info.abc();
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem as well.  I was using a HTTP service initially, but after switching to HTTPS I got the dreaded PolicyException.  

Initially I did `MyService ss = new MyService(new URL(wsdlUrl), new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "MyService")); IMyService port = ss.getBasicHttpBindingIMyService();`.   

Now I do `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean(); factory.setServiceClass(IMyService.class); factory.setAddress(wsdlUrl.replace("?wsdl", "")); IMyService port = (IMyService) factory.create();`.

Comment: I am getting the same problem ....while the code was working in tomcat  but when i deploy the code in jboss i am getting this error . can you please share the full code of client program .

Comment: From what place you took this soap suffix ? This way of generating client and set address from wsdl solved my problem. Thx u a lot. I'm so curious, Could you describe in more details why it's works ?

Answer (score 1):

You are awesome. this solved my issue of wsse:policy security problem in my wsdl. Now I can call the secured service using CXF.

I need to add following in my code

```
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean(); 
    factory.setServiceClass(TicketServicePortType.class); 
    factory.setAddress("http://localhost:8090/services"); 
    TicketServicePortType port = (TicketServicePortType) factory.create();

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

    http.getAuthorization().setUserName("user");
    http.getAuthorization().setPassword("password");


    Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

    Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "user");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, 
    ClientPasswordCallback.class.getName());

    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
    cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```

Comment: 1) it is better to use outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, new ClientPasswordCallback());
2) username/password initialization in http.getAuthorization() seems to be useless...

Answer (score 1):

For me removing **cxf-bundle** from project helped immediately:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.17</version>
</dependency>
```