# None of the policy altern. can be satisfied

Tags: java, webservices-client, cxf-client

I'm trying to create a Webservice Client with Apache CXF 3.0.12 and Java JDK 1.8. The Source Generation with wsdl2java looks good, but when i tried to connect to WS i got a exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.zJkvLisaGetReklaList(Unknown Source)
...
```

The Auth Section from the WSDL-File:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BN_XYZ">
        <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer uri="http://xml.sap.com/2006/11/esi/esp/binxml" xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/" wsp:Optional="true"/>
        <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer uri="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/soap/features/http-optimization" xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/" wsp:Optional="true"/>
        <sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd="http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/">false</sapattahnd:Enabled>
        <wsp:ExactlyOne xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:sapsp="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/security/policy" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:TransportToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:HttpsToken>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:HttpBasicAuthentication/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:HttpsToken>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:TransportToken>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Strict/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:TransportBinding>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

I have already tried some tips from the forum, but unfortunately without success.

For example: [Apache CXF - None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072500/apache-cxf-none-of-the-policy-alternatives-can-be-satisfied)

Has anyone perhaps a tip?

Thanks.
Ben